# stripe: node library into typescript and angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm developing with angular + typescript. I need to add stripe library in order to be able to add some payment methods...

I'm looking forward to [Stripe-node](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node) with [@types/stripe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/stripe).

How could I take advantadge of both? Could you provide any stuff short helping code?

Comment: What do you mean by "take advantage of both"?

Comment: As far I've been able to figure out `@types/stripe` provide only types and `stripe-node` connectivity. I thought `@types/stripe` is like a bridge...

Comment: Everything that's under `@types/...` are typings for libraries. This is required because most libraries are not written with TypeScript and do not provide typings.

Comment: What I don't quite understand is how to use both... by other side, should these @types be installed using 'typings install' tool? What's that exactly for?

Comment: The gist is that if you import library `foo` (written in plain JS), TypeScript can not infer any typings. Everything exposed by `foo` will have the `any` type. This is why you also have to `npm install @types/foo`. TypeScript will then associate the API of `foo` with `@types/foo` whenever you `import` something from `foo`. `@types` are TypeScript's way to do interop between JS and TS.