# Using typescript with javascript libraries

Tags: typescript

I've been watching `@types\` npm packages for a long time. I'm using them, but I don't quite figure out what do they exactly stand for.

I know that the main purpose of these libraries is to define types/classes/interfaces... getting them ready up for using them into typescript projects.

Currently, I'm intended for providing stripe features into a front-end. There are two npm libraries:

1. The official [stripe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stripe) library which is a straightforward javascript library.
2. There's another library [@types/stripe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/stripe) which only defines stripe types.

I'm developing an angular2 + typescript project and I'm getting different issues:

1. I've installed both. How should I use them?
2. I've realized that exists a `typings` tool in order to install I don't know what. What's this tool for?

**EDIT**

Up to now, and according to [this guide](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/wiki/How-to-include-jQuery):

```
npm install stripe --save
npm install @types/stripe --save-dev
```

and I've added this in to `webpack.common.js`:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    Stripe: 'stripe'
})
```

Then, into my typescript component I've added this:

```
import * as Stripe from '@types/stripe';
```

Nevertheless I'm getting this error:

> [ts] File '.../node_modules/@types/stripe/index.d.ts' is not a module.

I've also tried:

```
import stripePackage from 'stripe';
```

But I'm getting the same message:

```
[ts] File '.../node_modules/@types/stripe/index.d.ts' is not a module.
```

Comment: Diplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42834722/stripe-node-library-into-typescript-and-angular2 (Possibly same guy with different account? ...)

Answer (score 1):

The gist is that if you import library `foo`, which is written in plain JS, TypeScript can not infer any typings. Everything exposed by `foo` will have the `any` type.

This is why you also have to `npm install @types/foo`. TypeScript will then associate the API of `foo` with `@types/foo` whenever you import something from `foo`. `@types` is TypeScript's way to do interop between JS and TS.

Using `typings` is deprecated as of 2.0. You can read more about this here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/06/15/the-future-of-declaration-files/

Comment: So 1) I need to install both. 2) I don't quite get `Typescript will associate the API of foo with @types/foo` -> How should I "import" those libraries? / How TS makes this association?

Comment: If you're suing ES modules for example, using `import foo from 'foo'` will "associate" the types. If you're unfamiliar with this topic, I would suggest you to pic up a book or at least work through https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/

Comment: I've read really a lot. Nevertheless, I understand nothing! I'm using webpack + typescript + angular2 and I don't quite get how on earth import straightforwardly a js library. I'm really stuck!

Comment: If the library is in your `node_modules` folder, you should just be able to import libraries the same way you import stuff from `@angular/xxx`. If you do not have any typings, it will still work, but you will not get any type annotations.

Comment: I've added this line into my code: `import * as Stripe from '@types/stripe';`. However, I'm getting this message: `[ts] File '.../node_modules/@types/stripe/index.d.ts' is not a module.
`. You can see the content of `index.d.ts` [on here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/555ea54770b8576162e761e344de969d6e960869/stripe/index.d.ts)

Comment: You do not need to import `@types/xxx` rather import `stripe`. Because this is the *library*  you want. You're trying to import *type declarations*.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138307/discussion-between-user3227319-and-sebastian-sebald).